# Broken code-example link in ML Data Hub tutorial

Tags: marklogic

In the datahub tutorial, https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/tutorial/4x/harmonize-order-data-by-custom-code/

Under step:
3b - Customize the Content Plugin

Click the CONTENT tab.
Replace the content plugin code with the following:
Nothing is displayed - the page source shows it wants to import:

> raw.githubusercontent.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-data-hub/develop/examples/online-store/plugins/entities/Order/harmonize/Harmonize Orders/content/content.sjs

But that link reports: 404: Not Found

Where can I find the missing snippet?

Answer (score 1):

This will be added back to the docs soon, but in the meantime, this is the code that used to be reference there - https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/blob/71db3957114fd69f9cb584c6bfd38ec564410806/examples/online-store/plugins/entities/Order/harmonize/Harmonize%20Orders/content/content.sjs

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming if you take the 3 code snippets from the explanation just above and put them together like this:

```
var orders = jsearch
  .collections('Order')
  .documents()
  .where(
jsearch.byExample({
  'id': id
})
  )
  .result('value')
  .results.map(function(doc) {
return doc.document.envelope.instance;
  });


/* The following property is a local reference. */
var products = [];
var price = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
  var order = orders[i];
  if (order.sku) {
products.push(makeReferenceObject('Product', order.sku));
price += xs.decimal(parseFloat(order.price)) * xs.decimal(parseInt(order.quantity, 10));
  }
}


return {
  '$attachments': attachments,
  '$type': 'Order',
  '$version': '0.0.1',
  'id': id,
  'price': price,
  'products': products
}
```

that will give you the code for the createContent function. So, replace whatever is in the createContent function with the above snippet.